# Fill:selectcommand.connction property has not been initialised

Tags: c#-4.0, stored-procedures

i am getting error on  sda.Fill(dt); that Fill:selectcommand.connction property has not been initialised what could be a problem in connection?

```
 protected void Updatecustomer(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    string cstid = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblcustomerid")).Text;
    string csnm = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtname")).Text;
    string cmpn = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtcompany")).Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\LiveSms\\App_Data\\Sms.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "update gridCompany set name=@name,company=@company where cid=@cid;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cid", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cstid;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = csnm;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@comnpany", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmpn;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the `SelectCommand` of the DataAdapter, you are providing only a `UpdateCommand`.

Comment: ok done needed to add  cmd.Connection = con;
 and had spelling mistake at @company,didn't able to capture that mistake from last 1hr,and thanks